# How can I switch tabs in Chrome on Windows using Alt+Ctrl+LeftCursor/RightCursor

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

On *Mac* I can switch tabs in Chrome using `Cmd+Alt+LeftCursor/RightCursor`.

On *Windows* I have to use `Ctrl+Tab/Ctrl+Shift+Tab`.

How can I use `Alt+Ctrl+LeftCursor/RightCursor` on *Windows*?

It'd be ace if this could work in other programs too, not just in Chrome.

I have Windows 10.

Comment: CTRL-Tab, CTRL-Shift-Tab can be pressed with the left hand on the left hand side of the keyboard. Also one hand.

Comment: Why would it take two hands? All three keys are within less than 5 cm of each other.

Comment: I would use the thumb to press CTRL optionally shift, and the index finger for the tab.

Comment: There is no need of using two hands for Ctrl+Tab. Thumb and index finger is more than enough.

Comment: Apologies for my moment of idiocy - I have updated the question.

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in solution. You need to use a 3rd party app, like autohotkey to change shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+)<kbd>Tab</kbd>, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to navigate your tabs. Both shortcuts work in most browsers and most tabbed user interfaces you encounter in Windows.

Additionally, you can close tabs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in most browsers.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> on macOS is generally very similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Windows.